# Database update query for split and sum in another field using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table

```
test
ID       text       sum
-----------------------
1        1_2_3         0 

2        2_3_4_5       0
```

i want to update this table as

```
ID       text       sum
------------------------
1        1_2_3        6

2        2_3_4_5      14
```

how to write the query or function/procedure.

Comment: What have you been trying so far to get your result? Why do you store your values in a "_" separated list? Have a look at the documentation (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1):

You should really NORMALIZE your data,but assuming you are forced to work with it:

```
UPDATE tableName SET sum=SUBSTRING_INDEX(text,'_',1) +
 SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(text,'_0'),'_',2),'_',-1) +
 SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(text,'_0'),'_',3),'_',-1) +
 SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(text,'_0'),'_',4),'_',-1) +
 SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(text,'_0'),'_',5),'_',-1);
```

Use SUBSTRING _INDEX to isolate each number,CONCAT is used to give a 0 if the number of expressions is larger than the number of values.

[**The fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf211/1)

Comment: Thank you sir if i have 10 or 20 values then it is problem to write. Is there any solution

Comment: Either create a monster query for all 20 values or normalize your data.Its easy ,just copy the previous row and increment the number

Comment: Yes there is a solution - stop storing your data in a stupid way. There, I said it.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this solution...
Hope this will help you....

```
SELECT SUM(Trim( Left(Name, InStr(Name, "_") - 1)) + 
           Trim(  Mid(Name, InStr(Name, "_") + 1)) + 
           Trim(Right(Name, InStr(Name, ",") + 1))) as SUM FROM TEST;
```

Where the table structure is like this:

```
   Id |  Name     |
   1  | 1_2_3     |
   2  | 5_8_10    |
```

It's resulted as

```
SUM
 6
23
```

Comment: What if you have 4 values...or 20?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to go about this is to make each text field an SQL statement.

First, here is sample data

```
mysql> drop table if exists prabhu;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.27 sec)

mysql> create table prabhu
    -> (
    ->   id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    ->   text varchar(128),
    ->   sum int default 0
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.56 sec)

mysql> insert into prabhu (text) values ('1_2_3'),('2_3_4_5');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.09 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from prabhu;
+----+---------+------+
| id | text    | sum  |
+----+---------+------+
|  1 | 1_2_3   |    0 |
|  2 | 2_3_4_5 |    0 |
+----+---------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Here is a query to make each row produce an SQL statement to update the `sum` column

```
mysql> SELECT CONCAT('UPDATE prabhu SET sum=',
    -> REPLACE(text,'_','+'),' WHERE id=',id,';') sqlstmt FROM prabhu;
+-------------------------------------------+
| sqlstmt                                   |
+-------------------------------------------+
| UPDATE prabhu SET sum=1+2+3 WHERE id=1;   |
| UPDATE prabhu SET sum=2+3+4+5 WHERE id=2; |
+-------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Now, pipe the output of the query back into mysql and execute each line

```
C:\>mysql -Dtest -ANe"SELECT CONCAT('UPDATE prabhu SET sum=',REPLACE(text,'_','+'),' WHERE id=',id,';') sqlstmt FROM pra
bhu" | mysql -Dtest

C:\>mysql -Dtest -Ae"SELECT * FROM prabhu"
+----+---------+------+
| id | text    | sum  |
+----+---------+------+
|  1 | 1_2_3   |    6 |
|  2 | 2_3_4_5 |   14 |
+----+---------+------+

C:\>
```

## Give it a Try !!!

Comment: This is quite elegant and scalable,any way to do the same thing without the command line?