# How to add the numbers in comma separated string of numbers contained in a MySQL column?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL column which contains a string of scores separated by a semi-colon eg: "5;21;24;25;26;28;117".

This column was created not by design, but by collecting the values from multiple rows in a table using GROUP_CONCAT and GROUP BY. The original data arrived as a spreadsheet with multiple rows with the ID value.

I can use a select clause with REPLACE function to replace the ; with a +.

```
SELECT values, REPLACE(values,";","+") AS score FROM [table_name] WHERE 1

values                                score
5;21;24;25;26;28;117                  5+21+24+25+26+28+117
```

However what I need is the sum of: 5+21+24+25+26+28+117 to get a total of 246.

Is there any way to do this in MySQL without using some other scripting language?

The SELECT clause shows me a string of numbers joined with the + symbol.
Am looking for a way to evaluate that string to give me the result: 246

UPDATE:
As I was framing my question, I did more research and came up with this link which solves my problem:

(https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/120747/evaluate-a-string-value-as-a-computed-expression-in-an-sql-statement-sthg-like).

Am keeping this question and the link to the answer here in case it could help other people searching for the same.

Comment: You should actually change your table design. Never store multiple values in a single column!

Comment: Possible duplicate of the following link as there is difference of only a delimiter  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23381744/database-update-query-for-split-and-sum-in-another-field-using-mysql